# Which heating and cooking techniques can be developed and taught massively and quickly?

Tags: heating-systems

**HYPOTHESES:**

As an exercise in thought, let's take for granted some hypothesis:

1. Let's leave aside the "need for electricity" to focus on the need for warming up a house and cooking some food.
2. Let's leave aside the question of "if" fossil energies (from oil and gas to material powering nuclear centrals) availability will be reduced at some point in the future, and take it for granted.
3. Let's leave aside the question of "when" such reduction will happen (whether within the incoming 5 years or within the next 5000 years): maybe strategies to manage such reduction will differ depending of the time scope of such transition, but let's ignore this for the moment.

**QUESTION:**

Which sustainable techniques and technologies to cook food and heat homes can be developed and taught massively and quickly?

**MOTIVATION:**

There has been many human civilizations based on renewable energies. For instance, the western preindustrial era civilization was using sailing boats, wind and water mills, muscular force (human and non human).
One could fear that renouncing to the use of fossil energies would mean to "go back to such times", or at least go back to such technologies, a step back for "the human civilization".
But humanity as acquired a lot of scientific knowledge during the industrial era, which has been put in practice using fossil sources of energies, but could also be put in practice to design new technologies independent of them.

Now, one could wait for problems to present themselves in order to try to solve them, but some problems are better solved when given time to prepare their solution in anticipation of the time when they will come. In some parts of the world, people without access to fossil energies (for availability or for cost) are burning wood and other materials (in [potentially dangerous ways](https://www.portlandmercury.com/news/2017/11/29/19503402/as-winter-approaches-the-homeless-are-using-dangerous-methods-to-keep-warm)) to just stay warm in the winter. Experts warn of the risks of (traditional) wood burning stoves both [for people inside the home where it is used](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2021/jan/01/avoid-using-wood-burning-stoves-if-possible-warn-health-experts) and for the [cities where many people use such wood burning stoves](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2022/may/29/do-wood-burners-add-to-air-pollution-in-cities-yes-say-citizen-scientists).

Can humanity try to anticipate the times when lots of people will be cold and hungry from the lack of access to fossil sources of energies and try to develop healthy sustainable alternatives rather than leave them to improvise when the problem rise?

Comment: Did you mean "hypotheses"?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is likely to be closed as off-topic for this site. You need to ask a specific engineering question that can receive definite answers. The [Tour] explains it fairly well.

Comment: @Transistor Do you have any suggestion about where to ask more general questions about engineering?

Comment: Paying close attention to your title: cooking = get fuel on fire, heat food.  At a massive scale, think stews for long term.

Comment: This sounds more like a Worldbuilding SE question.